# Flyway: checksums and repeatable Java migrations

Tags: flyway

I have a problem with repeatable Java migrations in Flyway 4.2.0.

For example I wrote a repeatable Java migration, that creates for every table with a specific column a trigger. The ChecksumProvider for this migration calculates the hashcode of the concatenated names of tables with missing a trigger.

```
    @Override
    public int getChecksum(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        return queryTableNames(conn).stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")).hashCode();
    }
```

- When the list of tables is empty, the hashcode is zero and nothing should be done.
- When the list of tables is not empty, the hashcode is different from zero (name it xxx) and for every table a suiting trigger is added to the database. 
  In this case the hascode xxx is written to "schema_version". 
  The next time flyway:info is executed, it shows an outdated migration, because all triggers are present and the new checksum is zero. So I have to do a "flyway:repair" or a additional "flyway:migrate" to get a clean table "schema_version".

**Is there a simple opportunity to update the checksum after a Java repeatable Migration automatically?**

I examined FlywayCallback.afterEachMigrate, but there is only read-only access to MigrationInfo. Further steps using this approach would use too much flyway internals (i.e. updating "schema_version" separately).

Implementing an own MigrationResolver coupled with a custom MigrationExecutor seems to be too heavy-weight.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the checksum is wrong. The checksum should refer to the current target state.

In the example the method queryTableNames() should return all tables with such a trigger and the migration should complete these tables with the desired triggers.